# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'password')..?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose  = require("mongoose");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const router = express.Router();
const db = mongoose.connection;
const User = require("./db/User");
require("./db/config");
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/register', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/register.html')
});



app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/login', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html')
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.post("/registration", async(req,res)=> {
   
    const registerData = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password 
    });
    const registered =  await registerData.save();
    res.render("homepage.html");
});  

app.post("/login", async(req,res)=> {
   const email = req.body.email;
   const password = req.body.password;

   User.findOne({email:email}, (err , foundResults)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        if(foundResults.password === password){
          res.send('You logged in!')
        }else{
            res.send("incorrect password")
        }
    }
   })


});

app.listen(port),()=> {console.log(`on port 3000`);}
```

Terminal showing "Cannot read properties of null (reading password)" after login. Is there any way I can login without getting this error.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the login end-point on the client?

Comment: You mean the front-end  part..?

Comment: You can start debugging by console.log your request.body. Ensure the body are not `null` or `undefined`. e.g `console.log(request.body)`

Comment: Object showing null prototype.

Answer (score 0):

do it in a simple way

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email:email });
if(user && (user.password === password)){
return res.send('login successful');
}
return res.send('email and password not match');
```